# Opencv installed on mac but unable to use it through python console

Tags: python, macos, opencv, anaconda

Unable to install ‘opencv’ in macbook  OS X Yosemite Ver 10.10.5

Tried default installation, did not help then I installed Anaconda distribution of Python, after that again tried the following, I got the message saying opencv is installed, but Im unable to use it through python console. After installing Anaconda, i followed [this tutorial](http://www.jeffreythompson.org/blog/2013/08/22/update-installing-opencv-on-mac-mountain-lion/comment-page-1/) to install opencv

```
  $sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/include/
  $brew link eigen jpeg libpng libtiff ilmbase openexr numpy
  $sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
  $brew link eigen jpeg libpng libtiff ilmbase openexr numpy
  $brew install opencv --evn=std
  $brew link eigen jpeg libpng libtiff ilmbase openexr numpy
  $sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/lib/
  $brew link eigen jpeg libpng libtiff ilmbase openexr numpy
  $brew install opencv --evn=std
  $python
  $mkdir -p /Users/vikramchindam1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  $echo 'import site; site.addsitedir("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")' >> /Users/vikramchindam1/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/homebrew.pth
```

Then started the python console

```
 $python

>>> import cv
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 

[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.

Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org

>>> import cv

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

ImportError: No module named cv
```

I did multiple installations of Anaconda over a period of time is that an issue ? Following are the entries in my .bash_profile

```
alias textedit='open -a TextEdit'

# added by Anaconda 2.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/vikramchindam1/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

##
# Your previous /Users/vikramchindam1/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/vikramchindam1/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2015-06-06_at_15:09:19
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2015-06-06_at_15:09:19: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.


# added by Anaconda 2.2.0 installer
export PATH="/Applications/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda3 2.3.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/vikramchindam1/Documents/Anaconda-3/anaconda/bin:$PATH"

# added by Miniconda2 3.19.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/vikramchindam1/miniconda2/bin:$PATH"

# added by Anaconda2 2.5.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/vikramchindam1/Installations/Anacon-Python2-7/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Last entry "export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH" was added by me after installing opencv through this command "brew install opencv --env=std"

Please help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: try to import **cv2** instead

Comment: Tried but not working  >>>import cv2 .. ImportError: No module named cv2

Comment: Call to cv2 from Anaconda, not from your *normal* shell

Comment: Opened a terminal under Anaconda, tried but same error https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bxed_8T6OPe4OWxCdndwdHR1bDQ/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You must install OpenCV in Anaconda using 'conda' tool. You can try to type this in your terminal.

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv
```

This worked on my ubuntu 14.04, and I think it should work on Mac too.

You can find a detailed instruction in this link where I showed how to install OpenCV in Anaconda.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787748/installing-opencv-3-1-with-anaconda-python3/39240127#39240127
```

I hoped it helped you =)