# Installing opencv 3.1 with anaconda python3?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04

How do I install opencv with anaconda python3 , opencv picked up my python3 executables

```
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.12)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
--     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.0)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/tamim/anaconda3/bin/python3 (ver 3.5.2)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so (ver 3.5.2)
--     numpy:                       /home/tamim/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python3.5/site-packages
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
```

I installed opencv with the following make options

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D WITH_QT=ON -D WITH_OPENGL=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 -D CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-D_FORCE_INLINES" ..
```

But after installing it I can't import cv2 within python3 of anaconda. I can however import cv2 from builtin python2 command. So I suppose it build for the python2 version as stated in the last line.

How do I build for anaconda python3 ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think you don't need to build OpenCV for anaconda, there is this very handy
tool called 'conda' that is available in your terminal once you have installed
the Anaconda python distribution.

I found this site which gives instruction on how to install opencv3

```
https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3
```

I personally installed it myself so just try follow along with these instructions.

If you have the Anaconda python distribution installed in your system, you can issue this command (assuming you are working on linux) fire up the terminal:

```
conda install -c menpo opencv
```

If the version of python install in your Anaconda is 2.7, the command above should install OpenCV 3.1, but if the version of your python is 3.5, then you should change 'opencv' in the last line to 'opencv3'

```
conda install -c menpo opencv3
```

This should install OpenCV in your Anaconda. To see if you have installed it successfully, fire up your Python and issue the following command:

```
import cv2 # import the opencv library

cv2.__version__ # this will print the version of your opencv3
```

Hope that helps =)

Comment: Does this install with cuda support ?

Comment: I think the support for cuda is already in OpenCV. I found this link that says something about Cuda Module in OpenCV. You might wanna check it out. Here is the link:

    http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d2/dbc/cuda_intro.html

Comment: Missing colon in URL for opencv3

Comment: Thanks. This worked on 64bit Linux but not in 32bit Linux. In 32bit linux I get PackageNotFoundError

Comment: Yeah, I think there is no support for 32 bit linux

Comment: The full URL did not work for me (Python 3.5) but this worked `conda install -c menpo opencv3`

Comment: I could get it work by building OpenCV from source with argument to CMake as " -D BUILD_opencv_python3=yes " for python 3 support

Comment: It will be very helpful to explain the reason for downvoting so that we can improve this answer. thanks.

Comment: This method downgrade my python 3.6 to 2.7. However `conda install -c anaconda opencv` works. Probably this is the reason https://github.com/menpo/conda-opencv3/issues/21

Comment: Hi @MuhammadRaihanMuhaimin, thank you for that comment, Please feel free to update this answer :)

Comment: @TamimAddari No, to get cuda support you have to build openCV from source with flag -D WITH_CUDA=ON

Answer (score 24):

If you are getting an error like the following:

```
    UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
            opencv 2.4.11* -> numpy 1.9* -> python 2.6* -> openssl 1.0.1*
            python 3.6*
            Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Just install python 3.5 and try again.

```
conda install python=3.5
conda install -c menpo opencv  # whichever
conda install -c menpo opencv3 # you need
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this method it worked for me. Anaconda3-4

```
conda create -n opencv 
activate opencv
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/menpo opencv3
```

Answer (score 8):

None of the methods above worked for me. However, I found that this one liner works for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

Answer (score 8):

With conda v4.3.16 and python v3.6 this command worked for me:

```
conda install -c anaconda opencv
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to compile opencv against a specific anaconda environment, you can specify the `PYTHON_EXECUTABLE, PYTHON_INCLUDE` and `PYTHON_LIBRARY, PYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH, PYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR` variables in `cmake`.

In the following example I have an opencv340 anaconda environment located in /home/yourself/anaconda3/envs/opencv340 and so I'll specifiy the above variables for `cmake` as follows:

```
-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/home/yourself/anaconda3/envs/opencv340/bin/python3 \
-DPYTHON_INCLUDE=/home/yourself/anaconda3/envs/opencv340/include \
-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/home/yourself/anaconda3/envs/opencv340/lib/libpython3.6m.so \
-DPYTHON_PACKAGES_PATH=/home/yourself/anaconda3/envs/opencv340/lib/python3.6/site-packages \
-DPYTHON_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/yourself/anaconda3/envs/opencv340/lib/python3.6/site-packages/core/include
```

You'll then see that opencv pick the correct python, the one in the anaconda environment of which you gave the path of.

You then copy the cv2*.so from your opencv build directory to the `site-packages` of your anaconda environment.

Your `site-packages` directory should be located somewhere like:

/home/yourself/anaconda3/envs/opencv340/lib/python3.6/site-packages

You can get the actual location from a python console with:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(next(p for p in sys.path if 'site-packages' in p))
```

Then (adapt accordingly to your case and cv2*.so actual name):

`cp /path/to/your/opencv/build/directory/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /home/yourself/anaconda3/envs/opencv340/lib/python3.6/site-packages/.`

And you should be able to `import cv2` from a python console.

I've just done so (ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 3):

conda: **4.7.10**,
python: **3.7.3**,
channel: **default**

Installing `opencv` from the `default` channel worked for me. I installed into a clean environment and had no conflicts.

```
conda install opencv
```

```
The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  blas               pkgs/main/osx-64::blas-1.0-mkl
  bzip2              pkgs/main/osx-64::bzip2-1.0.8-h1de35cc_0
  cairo              pkgs/main/osx-64::cairo-1.14.12-hc4e6be7_4
  ffmpeg             pkgs/main/osx-64::ffmpeg-4.0-h01ea3c9_0
  fontconfig         pkgs/main/osx-64::fontconfig-2.13.0-h5d5b041_1
  freetype           pkgs/main/osx-64::freetype-2.9.1-hb4e5f40_0
  gettext            pkgs/main/osx-64::gettext-0.19.8.1-h15daf44_3
  glib               pkgs/main/osx-64::glib-2.56.2-hd9629dc_0
  graphite2          pkgs/main/osx-64::graphite2-1.3.13-h2098e52_0
  harfbuzz           pkgs/main/osx-64::harfbuzz-1.8.8-hb8d4a28_0
  hdf5               pkgs/main/osx-64::hdf5-1.10.2-hfa1e0ec_1
  icu                pkgs/main/osx-64::icu-58.2-h4b95b61_1
  intel-openmp       pkgs/main/osx-64::intel-openmp-2019.4-233
  jasper             pkgs/main/osx-64::jasper-2.0.14-h636a363_1
  jpeg               pkgs/main/osx-64::jpeg-9b-he5867d9_2
  libgfortran        pkgs/main/osx-64::libgfortran-3.0.1-h93005f0_2
  libiconv           pkgs/main/osx-64::libiconv-1.15-hdd342a3_7
  libopencv          pkgs/main/osx-64::libopencv-3.4.2-h7c891bd_1
  libopus            pkgs/main/osx-64::libopus-1.3-h1de35cc_0
  libpng             pkgs/main/osx-64::libpng-1.6.37-ha441bb4_0
  libtiff            pkgs/main/osx-64::libtiff-4.0.10-hcb84e12_2
  libvpx             pkgs/main/osx-64::libvpx-1.7.0-h378b8a2_0
  libxml2            pkgs/main/osx-64::libxml2-2.9.9-hf6e021a_1
  mkl                pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl-2019.4-233
  mkl_fft            pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl_fft-1.0.12-py37h5e564d8_0
  mkl_random         pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl_random-1.0.2-py37h27c97d8_0
  numpy              pkgs/main/osx-64::numpy-1.16.4-py37hacdab7b_0
  numpy-base         pkgs/main/osx-64::numpy-base-1.16.4-py37h6575580_0
  opencv             pkgs/main/osx-64::opencv-3.4.2-py37h6fd60c2_1
  pcre               pkgs/main/osx-64::pcre-8.43-h0a44026_0
  pixman             pkgs/main/osx-64::pixman-0.38.0-h1de35cc_0
  py-opencv          pkgs/main/osx-64::py-opencv-3.4.2-py37h7c891bd_1
  zstd               pkgs/main/osx-64::zstd-1.3.7-h5bba6e5_0
```

```
$python                                                                                                
Python 3.7.3 (default, Mar 27 2019, 16:54:48)
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'3.4.2'
>>>
```