# anaconda ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, machine-learning, pip, anaconda

I am trying to install opencv on my laptop but I keep getting `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: The specified module could not be found.`
I tried installing installing with `conda install -c conda-forge opencv` in an anaconda env.
But I also get the same result if I use my normal python 3.10 interpreter with `opencv-python` and `opencv-contrib-python`.
I also tried to compile the module myself but `cv2.cp310-win_amd64` gives me the same error as well...

Isnt there just an prebuild binary I can use? or should I look for an different ML module?

Yesterday when I came home I tried installing `opencv-python` on my personal computer. And it worked instantly. I have an GTX 1070 in that pc and an RTX A1000 in the work laptop I need opencv on. So I tought that the cuda cores might not be supported or something.
I found this tutorial https://machinelearningprojects.net/build-opencv-with-cuda-and-cudnn/
But after installing the Nvidia SDK, cudnn and compiling opencv from source I still get the same error.
Even with appending the opencv output folder and the cuda sdk bin folder to python's dll_path.

Disabling `BUILD_SHARED_LIBS` as suggested in here also does nothing....
https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-w-cuda-build-seems-successful-but-import-cv2-fails/11328/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using python 3.6 with `conda install -c conda-forge opencv=3.2.0` as described here [OpenCV-Python ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668602/opencv-python-importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-fo?rq=1) solved the issue on my laptop with an RTX A1000. Weird opencv works with python 3.10 on my desktop with an GTX 1070

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me just this morning, and I fixed it by installing opencv using pip. First, I removed conda's opencv installation. In the environment where it is installed type

`conda remove opencv`

Once it is removed, type

`pip install opencv-python`

Hope it helps

Comment: sadly it didnt help......

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).