# Python3 + OpenCV3 binding on mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, opencv, homebrew, pyenv

I am trying to build environment to use `opencv3` with `python3` and now following the instructions in [this webpage](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/).

Although I have already installed `OpenCV3` with `Python3` bindings via `Homebrew`, I could not find them. According to above webpage, they should be in:

```
/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

However, I found nothing but in:

```
/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

I have no idea why there is not python3.6 directory in:

```
/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib/
```

Anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: Did you install python3? What do you get when you run python3 --version?

Comment: It's easier to set up opencv3 on Mac with Anaconda. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38787748/installing-opencv-3-1-with-anaconda-python3) for more info.

Comment: Yes, installed. I've got this: Python 3.6.1.

Comment: Did you do `brew install opencv3 --with-python3`? If yes, then may be you don't have numpy installed. Make sure you have `numpy` by `pip3 install numpy`.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any resolution so far?